# Do closed testing and internal testing tracks support auto update?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

My question is about closed and internal tracks. As you know in the production track users are able to update their app automatically by enabling auto-update in the google play store. I want to do the same thing in Closed and Internal  Testing tracks,  I tried but when I updated my application in the google play console I did not receive auto-update.  So question is that do close and internal testing tracks support this feature?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Auto-update is a feature from the Play Store app, independent from the Play Console. As long as the user/device is eligible for a version that has a higher versionCode (and auto-update is enabled), the user will update to the new version automatically, regardless of whether it comes from a testing track or a production track.

Note: Not to confuse however testing track with [internal app sharing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844679?hl=en-GB) where the APKs are in this case signed with a different key, so a manual update would be needed from the user.

Comment: Thank you,  but what do you mean by a different key? The signing key is the same for all of the versions of my app.

Comment: Are you using internal app sharing? If not, this shouldn't be a concern for you. 
If you use internal app sharing, Play re-signs the APK with a key they generate and users have to opt in in the settings of Play Store to accept installing such apps, so it's not auto-update.